# Catch/Display errors in client side without console logs

Tags: exception, promise

When a promise is called in the client side. What is the best way to catch/display error without console.log()? Example as follows

```
  .then(result => {

  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for:

console.error = () => { throw new Error(FEATURES_ERROR); };

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error